# Outputting predicted values in SAS proc mixed: Prohibitive performance issues

Tags: sas

I've noticed strange behavior with SAS proc mixed: Models with a modestly large number of rows, which take only seconds to converge, nevertheless take upwards of half an hour to finish running if I ask for output of predicted values & residuals. The thing that seems perverse is that when I run the analogous models in R using nlme::lme(), I get the predicted values & residuals as a side effect and the models complete in seconds. That makes me think this is not merely a memory limitation of my machine.

Here's some sample code. I can't provide the real data for which I'm seeing this issue, but the structure is 1-5 rows per subject, ~1500 unique subjects, ~5,000 outcome-covariate sets total.

In SAS:

```
proc mixed data=testdata noclprint covtest;
    class subjid ed gender;
    model outcome = c_age ed gender / ddfm=kr solution residual outp=testpred;
    random int c_age / type=un sub=subjid;
run;
```

In R:

```
lme.test <- lme(outcome ~ c_age + ed + gender, data=testdata, 
               random = ~c_age|factor(subjid), na.action=na.omit)
```

Relevant stats: Win7, SAS 9.4 (64-bit), R 3.3, nlme 3.1-131.

Comment: How many pages of (printed) output do you get?  (Or asked another way, assuming you get HTML back, are you getting a huge amount of output?)  SAS is notoriously bad at handling really large amounts of _printed_ output (as opposed to datasets which it's notoriously good with).  I wonder if asking for the predicted values and residuals is filling up your output/results window and causing SAS to misbehave.

Comment: I've been running this in batch and outputting to PDF rather than HTML; regardless it's only about 6 pages of output total (2 pages per model).

Comment: Could you post a synthetic dataset that has the same general code and same general issue?  I'm afraid I don't know `proc mixed` well enough to make a synthetic dataset that would actually work.

Comment: Set the FULLSTIMER option and run again, post your log. There should be data in the documentation examples that can fit this scenario, to replicate the issue if you can't post your real data please use that data to mock up a similar situation. Without the ability to replicate your issue we can't really help.

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/03/11/sas-fullstimer-turn-it-on/